# simple it seems yet having trouble with an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this class of code and one piece of code just stops the whole thing from working and i am unable to figure out why.

Scenario: The method will send a json as a reply when called via ajax, the code works fine except for the if condition.

> ```
>         if(false) // this stops the script
>         {
>         $menu[] = new jsTreeNode('node','nodeid');
>         }
>         $menu[] = new jsTreeNode('node');
> ```

Actual if condition is a comparision of two values and not just false, if i put true or when the actual condition is true it works fine but false just stops the whole script. Any ideas??

Edit:

```
public function __construct($title, $nodeID = NULL)
{
    $this->data = new stdClass();
    $this->data->title = $title;
    $this->data->icon = 'assets/img/icons/'.strtolower($title).'.png';
    $this->attr = new stdClass();
    $this->attr->id = ($nodeID == NULL) ? strtolower($title) : strtolower($nodeID);

}

public function addChild($title, $nodeID = NULL)
{
    $this->children[] = new jsTreeNode($title, $nodeID);    
}
```

**error_reporting throws no error.**

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and please show us what your if condition actually tests, and what your `jsTreeNode` constructor looks like.

Comment: Would using something like `if(!true)` work?

Comment: If your if condition has a function call it could be causing the error. What does it look like?

Comment: @BoltClock if($var1==$var2){} @jeremysawesome Nopes that won't work either. Very weird

Comment: Does PHP spit any errors if you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: This is... puzzling. What does your Ajax call and your code before the if statement look like?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: after looking at your code you should always use the build in function of php to test values like null.

Try this:

```
$menu[] = (is_null($condition))? new jsTreeNode('node','nodeid') : new jsTreeNode('node');
```

Comment: `new jsTreeNode('node')` needs to be created regardless of whether the condition is true or false.

Comment: I dont see your point, it will be created one way ro the other. But i dont see the need to usea block for just one line :P

Comment: Boltclock is right, i am using the jstreenode to add multiple nodes, i just needed this node to be called under a specific condition thats all. On the other hand you are right about block of code just for a statement but i am just testing now and i don't care for code neatness at the moment

Comment: Hey your both wright i just dont understod where this was going but try using is_null function, i'm no fan of $value == NULL

Answer (score 0):

This is from the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

> If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP
>   will execute statement, and if it
>   evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it.

Your expression by design evaluates to false and so PHP ignores it.

My guess is that using something like `if(!true)` would work better because if the condition you are giving the if statement is false, then the if statement would evaluate it as true.

Comment: No, he means the PHP script dies completely when the condition evaluates to false, which shouldn't happen under proper circumstances.

Comment: Yes exactly, just to avoid confusion please refer my comment to Boltclock in the main question, the ifcondition goes something like if($var==$var2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out but i figured the problem out it seems there is an addchild call going to the $menu[] of agent node which was causing the bug. So when it was false the if condition worked fine but due to the missing agent node the script just stopped loading. Since it was an ajax call i only figured it out now. Thanks all the same to everyone!